# XAML Checkbox Background and BorderBrush colors don't change on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, mouseover

How can i change CheckBox `BorderBrush` and `Background` Colors on `MouseOver`? I tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
<CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource checkBox}">CheckBoxText</CheckBox>
```

And here is my style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="checkBox">

    <!-- This part changes the colors -->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />

    <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

            <!-- This part is not changing the colors -->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />

        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Changing these colors works for `<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">` condition. But it's not working for `IsMouseOver`.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the `TargetName` to tell it what object you're applying your setter changes to. So for example just take your;

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
```

and make it;

```
<Setter TargetName="ObjectNameToChangeStuff" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
```

Where objectname is assumed to probably be a border or something so it would be something like

```
<Border x:Name="ObjectNameToChangeStuff"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

PS - Since I just noticed. You'll want those triggers in your ControlTemplate not your Style, so it would be `ControlTemplate.Triggers` instead of `Style.Triggers` (since you're interacting with elements of the ControlTemplate) with an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for comparison so you can spot your differences easier. :)

ADDED:

So if you have your template setup something like this (in pseudo);

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
  <!-- Blah blah setter stuff for defaults -->
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="DefaultColorForThisThing"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">

       <BlahBlah Stuff/>...

      <!-- Whatever CLR object that supports it, for example -->
      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

...then you should be able to pass a value at the dependency property to talk to the object inside the control template via just style triggers.

Comment: I wonder how `IsChecked` condition can change control colors with a simple style trigger but `IsMouseOver` can not. Is writing a complete control template the only way to change the background?

Comment: IsChecked is a dependency property of the control, IsMouseOver is an event at the control, and the setter has to hit an object inside the controltemplate. Yeah I think so. Unless you template bind Background property to the object inside the control template. Then you can sure.

Comment: If you want I can show you to do that to in just a bit but not from my phone :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still trying to figure this out, you could style and override the control template like so:

```
<Style x:Key="checkboxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Width="13" Height="13" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Orange" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid>
                                <Path Visibility="Collapsed" Width="7" Height="7" x:Name="CheckMark" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0">
                                    <Path.Stroke>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                                    </Path.Stroke>
                                </Path>
                                <Path Visibility="Collapsed" Width="7" Height="7" x:Name="InderminateMark" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 0 7 L 7 0">
                                    <Path.Stroke>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                                    </Path.Stroke>
                                </Path>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="InderminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Where:

- Border = Blue
- Background = Orange
- Tick/cross = Black
- Border on `Pressed` and `MouseOver` = LightBlue
- Background on `Pressed` and `MouseOver` = Yellow

I have slightly modified this [example template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates#checkbox-controltemplate-example) to account for hover over border color as well.

PS: this is a very naive approach, there's definitely a way to condense this down, I am a wpf beginner as well :P

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to override the OnMouseOver event with no success. I agree with Yoghurt that making a template is the best solution. However instead of drawing the checkmark using Path I would recommend using a Unicode character. See wikipedia for different unicode characters. WPF may not support some of the newer unicode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark